# why am i only getting the return of the help_syntax function when ran even with my args $1 and $2 completed?

Tags: bash

My code will only provide two options. one) the create_file function or two) then help_syntax function. I cannot figure out why. I am very new to Bash scripting, in fact Kali Linux alone and I'm trying to make a code to append new aliases to the `~/.zsh_aliases` file I've created. Please run this code and provide pointers for me in the right direction. Please fully explain you answer so I can learn from my mistakes as well.

I've been through different variations of the code, originally it was just a bunch of `if` and `elif` statements but I ran into an issue when i didn't know how to test the code for `if this is that AND this is that_2 then execute` so I changed to functions where I could separate into sections and execute accordingly.

```
#! /bin/bash

# Functions
function help_syntax () {
    echo "Syntax: ./allyAppend.sh {alias_name} \"{command}\""
    echo "Example: ./allyAppend.sh upug \"sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y\""
}
    
function append () {
    if [ -z $1 ];
    then    
        help_syntax     
    elif [ ! -z $1 ] && [ ! -z $2 ];
    then
        echo "alias $1=\"$2\"" >> ./test
        #source ~/.zshrc    
    fi          
}

function create_file () {
    if [ -z $1 ];
    then    
        help_syntax 
    elif [ ! -z $1 ] && [ ! -z $2 ];
    then
        read -p "[X] Error:: ~/.zsh_aliases doesnt exsist. Create the file and add your alias [y/N]?: " add
        if [ $add == "y" ]; then
            touch ./test
            echo "alias $1=\"$2\"" >> ./test
            echo "[X] NOTICE: You must edit your ~/.zshrc file to allow the aliases file" >> ./README
            echo "      enter::  if [ -f ~/.zsh_aliases ]; then
                            . ~/.zsh_aliases
                             fi 
                             :: at line 254 in ~/.zshrc and dont forget to tab in" >> ./README
        fi
    else
        echo "[:(] Good Bye! Thank You"
    fi  
}

# Tests if alias file exsists
if [ -f "./test" ]; 
then
    append
else
    create_file
fi
```

Comment: Please try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance. Why are you using `.zsh_aliases` if your shell is Bash? Zsh and Bash are distinct shells with different configuration files, different features, and syntax.

Comment: Aliases are flawed in many ways anyway; probably use shell functions instead.

Comment: I do acknowledge there is a difference in zsh and bash, and it’s not that I want to have a program to append aliases for me it’s the concept of me making a project because I was bored and want to learn a new language if this was python or c or Java or c++ I would be fine, my terminal is not in bash it’s zsh, hence the use of ~/.zsh_aliases

Comment: Do all the spaces and indents and extra lines matter? I use them to organize my code

Comment: Whitespace is generally insignificant in shell scripts. Still baffled as to why you would write a Bash script to manage Zsh aliases. Did you try shellcheck.net? It actually tells you what's wrong.

Comment: Correction: whitespace at the beginning of lines is generally insignificant, but whitespace between syntactic elements is usually critical. For example, if you remove *any* of the spaces in `if [ -z $1 ];`, it will either cause an error or change the meaning of the command. But I second the recommendation of shellcheck.net; it will point out the current problem, along with a bunch of potential future problems.

Comment: I check spell check I’ll test the code later and post accordingly thank you very much guys I really appreciate it, I though you meant spell check because of my bad grammar errors within the question